# Problem at editing page

Tags: header-footer, tex-core

I can't edit this style and I don't know why ? how can help me ?

http://naturalspublishing.com/show.asp?JorID=7&pgid=28

Comment: Could you please clarify your question, what are you attempting to edit? and what error did you get when you tried?

Comment: yes dear David I need all change in it, like title author ... but unfortunately even the sample not work

Comment: When I ran it, it need tex\latex\lastpage\lastpage.sty, and when I install it still I have an error

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what your question is, and I would guess most others would have the same problem. Please post a small document that shows your problem, and post the exact TeX error that you get.

Comment: ok, are you visit this site http://naturalspublishing.com/show.asp?JorID=7&pgid=28 
 and click on this phrase 
 Click here to download a formatted sample file.

Comment: this is my error when I open the file
it seems that this file cannot be correctly decoded with the default  encoding setting (UTF-8)

Comment: That is not a TeX error it is presumably an error from whatever editor you are using but you haven't even said what that is.

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `lastpage.sty' not found.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to compile it.

For some reason I can't explain myself it did produce an error in **NSP1.cls** at **line 573**:

```
\definecolor{rulecolor}{named}{Green}
```

stating `` undefined color: `Green'. `` Changin the line to

```
\definecolor{rulecolor}{RGB}{0,255,0}
```

did do the trick. It now compiles without errors. Was that your problem?

---

You commented, that there are issues with the [`lastpage`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage) package.

> File `lastpage.sty' not found.

It is used in **NSP1.cls** at **line 80**:

```
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
```

But in **lines 336 - 351**, it seems that the functionality of lastpage.sty (which is nothing more than providing a reference to the last page to use in 'page X of Y' constructs) is copy-pasted into the style file, rendering line 80 completely unnecessary. Change line 80 to

```
%\RequirePackage{lastpage}
```

or delete it altogether. Compiles without errors or change of output.

Another way would be to install the [`lastpage`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage) package by the means provided to you by the TeX distribution you are using (MikTeX, TeX Live, MacTex, ...). Since you said, you did try to install the package, the persistence of the error suggests, that that failed.

Comment: thanks Tobias but still does not work

Comment: Then please copy-paste your error message.

Comment: dear Tobias, if u want to understand me please see this site and 
naturalspublishing.com/show.asp?JorID=7&pgid=28

Comment: http://naturalspublishing.com/show.asp?JorID=7&pgid=28

Comment: Oh come on. I have seen the site. I did compile it. It works for me. That's in my answer. So what is your problem? Could it be that you haven't actually saved and extracted the .zip file, thus having issues with write protection?

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `lastpage.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: